# Recommended Memory Usage

Tags: memory

Perhaps a silly question, but I have read the man pages and githubs and can't find answer:

Are there any minimum memory allotment recommendations for `brotli` and `7zip` on linux at the highest levels of compression.

I am contemplating using them with `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=XXXm /path/to/my/script.sh`

I want to be sure to allot enough memory not to crash the apps

Comment: No idea about brotli, don't use it. 7z can use as little as several megabytes of RAM to as much as terabytes (I'm not joking) of RAM depending on its invocation. No one knows how you're gonna use the latter, so it's up to you to decide.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov brotli is hailed as the successor to `.gz`, but there doesn't seem to be a lot documentation on how to invoke it with exploding your machine having it spit acid in your face... :-/   My use case is simple...  changing Virtualmin Backups from `tar.gz` to `tar.br`

Comment: Most compressors/archivers use a defined amount of RAM (again depending on specified options), so there's no need to limit their RAM use cause otherwise they most likely will simply fail. I know nothing about brotli, recently I've been a fan of ZSTD, 7z and RAR. I terms of the number of compressed files by archiver, RAR is like 95%, 7z - 4.5%, ZSTD 0.5% of files.